# Return results from function for $body of email

Tags: powershell

The script below is excellent but I am unable to figure out how to assign it to a string that can be used as the body of an email. Can someone help a newbie on this one?

```psh
#Requires -Version 2.0
Function Get-LockedOutLocation {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  This function will locate the computer that processed a failed user logon attempt which caused the user account to become locked out.

.DESCRIPTION
  This function will locate the computer that processed a failed user logon attempt which caused the user account to become locked out.
  The locked out location is found by querying the PDC Emulator for locked out events (4740).
  The function will display the BadPasswordTime attribute on all of the domain controllers to add in further troubleshooting.

.EXAMPLE
  PS C:\>Get-LockedOutLocation -Identity Joe.Davis

  This example will find the locked out location for Joe Davis.

.NOTE
  This function is only compatible with an environment where the domain controller with the PDCe role to be running Windows Server 2008 SP2 and up.
  The script is also dependent the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module, which requires the AD Web services to be running on at least one domain controller.
  Author:Jason Walker
  Last Modified: 3/20/2013
#>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$Identity
    )

    Begin {
        $DCCounter = 0
        $LockedOutStats = @()

        Try {
            Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
        } Catch {
            Write-Warning $_
            Break
        }
    }#end begin

    Process {
        #Get all domain controllers in domain
        $DomainControllers = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *
        $PDCEmulator = ($DomainControllers | Where-Object {$_.OperationMasterRoles -contains "PDCEmulator"})

        $pdcemulator

        Write-Verbose "Finding the domain controllers in the domain"
        Foreach ($DC in $DomainControllers) {
            $DCCounter++
            Write-Progress -Activity "Contacting DCs for lockout info" -Status "Querying $($DC.Hostname)" -PercentComplete (($DCCounter/$DomainControllers.Count) * 100)
            Try {
                $UserInfo = Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity  -Server $DC.Hostname -Properties AccountLockoutTime,LastBadPasswordAttempt,BadPwdCount,LockedOut -ErrorAction Stop
            } Catch {
                Write-Warning $_
                Continue
            }
            If ($UserInfo.LastBadPasswordAttempt) {
                $LockedOutStats += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    Name                   = $UserInfo.SamAccountName
                    SID                    = $UserInfo.SID.Value
                    LockedOut              = $UserInfo.LockedOut
                    BadPwdCount            = $UserInfo.BadPwdCount
                    BadPasswordTime        = $UserInfo.BadPasswordTime
                    DomainController       = $DC.Hostname
                    AccountLockoutTime     = $UserInfo.AccountLockoutTime
                    LastBadPasswordAttempt = ($UserInfo.LastBadPasswordAttempt).ToLocalTime()
                }
            }#end if
        }#end foreach DCs
        $LockedOutStats | Format-Table -Property Name,LockedOut,DomainController,BadPwdCount,AccountLockoutTime,LastBadPasswordAttempt -AutoSize

        #Get User Info
        Try {
            Write-Verbose "Querying event log on $($PDCEmulator.HostName)"
            $LockedOutEvents = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $PDCEmulator.HostName -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';Id=4740} -ErrorAction Stop | Sort-Object -Property TimeCreated -Descending
        } Catch {
            Write-Warning $_
            Continue
        }#end catch

        Foreach ($Event in $LockedOutEvents) {
            If ($Event | Where {$_.Properties[2].value -match $UserInfo.SID.Value}) {
                $Event | Select-Object -Property @(
                    @{Label = 'User';               Expression = {$_.Properties[0].Value}}
                    @{Label = 'DomainController';   Expression = {$_.MachineName}}
                    @{Label = 'EventId';            Expression = {$_.Id}}
                    @{Label = 'LockedOutTimeStamp'; Expression = {$_.TimeCreated}}
                    @{Label = 'Message';            Expression = {$_.Message -split "`r" | Select -First 1}}
                    @{Label = 'LockedOutLocation';  Expression = {$_.Properties[1].Value}}
                )
            }#end ifevent
        }#end foreach lockedout event
    }#end process
}#end function

Get-LockedOutLocation -Identity y59x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is an object, or a list of objects. You need to transform it into a string for sending it via e-mail. Depending on what you want the mail body to look like, you could do something like this:

```psh
$body = Get-LockedOutLocation -Identity y59x |
        Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
```

or like this:

```psh
$body = Get-LockedOutLocation -Identity y59x | Format-List | Out-String
```

or (if you want to send HTML mail) like this:

```psh
$body = Get-LockedOutLocation -Identity y59x | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to grab the data from the event in the Foreach ($Event in $LockedOutEvents) loop.

Comment: So I just use out-string after that loop with -stream and it seems to work! Thanks :)