# Create variable from Microsoft Security event ID message for Account Name and Caller Computer Name

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log

I am using PowerShell to pull the most recent event ID for a locked out user using the following code:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Security"; ID=4740} -MaxEvents 1
```

Then I turn the message into a variable. When I show the message it looks like the screen below. How can I parse the data to create two separate variables. The first variable would be the Account Name and the second variable would be the caller computer name. So I should end up with below

```
$Account = []
$Caller = []
```

[image]

Comment: Why the downvotes here? OP is asking a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event-type-specific information of a given log entry is surfaced via the `.Properties` collection of the [`EventLogRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord) objects returned by [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent), which contains *values* only (no property *names*), which can be extracted via each element's `.Value` property

Therefore, you need to know the *indices* of the values of interest in order to extract them.

I infer from the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30968824/45375) that indices `0` and `1` refer to the locked-out user's username and the machine on which the lockout occurred, respectively.

Therefore:

```bash
$evt = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Security"; ID=4740} -MaxEvents 1

$account, $computer = $evt.Properties[0, 1].Value
```

Note the use of the following techniques:

- A *multi-assigment* (multiple target variables on the LHS)
- PowerShell's support for *multiple indices*, which returns the targeted elements *as an array*.
- [Member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration): the ability to access a property on a *collection* to have the property values of *its elements* returned.